# WPF - Force ShowDialog to return

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modal-dialog, showdialog

How can I force `ShowDialog` to return from a background thread?

I have a WPF application built on top of a C++/CLR framework which is listening to messages sent by the framework. One particular message is so important that I need to close all the current windows. However, if a modal `Dialog` (created by `ShowDialog` from my main window) is active and awaiting user input, the window will not close because it is waiting for `ShowDialog` to return. How can I force the modal `Dialog` to close and unwind code execution?

I tried setting the `DialogResult` or calling `Close` however that doesn't seem to work.

Edit: The `Dialog` is created by my main window which expects a return value, like so:
(inside a click event handler in `MainWindow`):

```
Window modalDialog = new Window();
bool ret = (bool)modalDialog.ShowDialog();
if (ret == true)
{
 // do stuff
}
else
{
 // do some other stuff
}
```

When the framework sends a message (coming in on a different thread than the UI thread), I call `MainWindow.Close()`. The modal dialog gets closed at this point, however the code checking the return value of the `Dialog` (after `ShowDialog`) is still on the stack.  Somehow this forces the main window to not disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the dialog receives the WM_CLOSE message it sets a flag that causes ShowDialog to return after the WM_CLOSE and any containing messages have been fully processed.  So if you are doing a `Dispatcher.Invoke()` onto your thread to call `MainWindow.Close()`, the `ShowDialog()` won't return until after the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` has completed.

So the simple solution is to return from the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to get the `ShowDialog()` to return.  If more processing is required, do another `Dispatcher.Invoke()` immediately afterwards.

If you are doing the thread transition some other way than `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, or if the `ShowDialog()` doesn't return after the Dispatcher.Invoke() call returns, you may have to post some of the code surrounding your `Window.Close()` call so we can see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force ShowDialog to return but you can have the window listen to an event sent by your framework that can tell it to close. In the example below Progress event has a "Done" flag the closes the window when done.

```
SomeGenerator IG = Manager.SomeGenerator();
SomeWindow PP = new SomeWindow();
IG.ProgressEvent += PP.ProgressEvent;
IG.ExecuteAsync();            
PP.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I edited my original question to indicate that ShowDialog is expected to return a value and the parent window is supposed to do some processing with the value...

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that I cannot force ShowDialog to return and continue execution whenever I want it to. The event handler for the request that I receive from the framework needs go out of context so the call stack can be unwound and the modal dialog can process the Close message.

I ended up setting a boolean flag, requesting the modals to close, then return from my framework event handler. Only at this point will ShowDialog return and I can check for the flag I set and continue with the requested action.

Comment: It sounds like my answer was the correct one and helped you solve your problem.  If you agree you should mark it "correct" for future visitors.